# splitting a large javascript file into several smaller files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, separation-of-concerns

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI to operate on DOM elements, and find myself in this situation.

**index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script src="dashboard.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.js**:

```
function addAccordian() {
  // some logic here
}

function addConnectedSortable() {
  // more logic here
}

function addPiecharts() {
  // a huge chunk of logic here

  // for example, 

  // several ...
  // hundred ...
  // line ...
  // of code

}

function readyFn(jQuery) {
  addAccordian();
  addConnectedSortable();
  addPiecharts();
}

$(document).ready(readyFn);
```

I can only picture the `dashboard.js` file grow bigger and bigger with time.

**Question**: Is there a way to split it into several smaller javascript files, and somehow `include`/`import` them?

I am coming from a Java background, so forgive me if the question does not make much sense.

I'm open to any suggestions, since this project is still early and we are flexible with technologies we use.

Comment: yup. that's often called a build process. Can be done using things like webpack/gulp/grunt for example.

Comment: i found [this article](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) solves some name conflicts issues. search for "module pattern"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the files you need and then include them in the page. I suggest that you include them in the head element so that the browser can load them concurrently.

```html
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i'll accept this answer. see my comment in the question for a solution for name conflicts